# ASP.Net Core static files not served

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

I'm porting an old application to net core framework and I have to serve files for my SPA from the web directory:

I have this code in my Startup.cs

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        app.UseDefaultFiles();
        app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
        {
            FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
        Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"web")),
            RequestPath = new PathString("/web")
        });
```

I have a web directory at the root of my project and a simple index.html file with Hello World in it.

[image]

If I try to access this url http://localhost:12345/web or http://localhost:12345/web/index.html the browser is waiting a response from the web browser.

[image]

Problem was in applicationhost.config:

```
  <site name="MyProject" id="5">
    <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
      <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\Dev\MyProject\srccore\MyWeb" />
    </application>
    <application path="/web" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
      <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\Dev\MyProject\src\MyOldSpa" />
    </application>
    <bindings>
                <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:53053:localhost" />
    </bindings>
  </site>
```

I had to remove the old virtual app directory:

```
    <application path="/web" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
      <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\Dev\MyProject\src\MyOldSpa" />
    </application>
```

Static files are served now, but I still have a problem, I have to specify index.html in the url

Finally for the default files replacing:

```
app.UseDefaultFiles();
```

to

```
app.UseDefaultFiles("/web");
```

make it works!

Comment: Just to confirm, could you post your directory structure? When you use the file provider like this it's going to the root of your project (e.g. a directory above wwwroot), just want to make sure that is the case.

Comment: if you try http://localhost:12345/web/index.html ?

Comment: nothing... the browser is waiting for a response

Comment: did you start application listening to the right port and you say that the root of the (static file handlers is the `web` folder) so the url `localhost/web/index.html` would lead to filsystem: `web/web/index.html` (see double web, is that intended?)

Comment: Is it possible to move the `web` folder inside `wwwroot` and let default static file middleware handle it?